# JAVA RandomAccessFile throws IOException when constructed

Tags: java, ioexception, randomaccessfile

I am trying to access a file to read it and write on it using this code:

```
RandomAccessFile file1 = new RandomAccessFile("C:\\lol.txt", "rw");
```

It returns me an error "File not Found (IOException)".

The file exists and it is in that exact folder. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have permission to write to the file?

Comment: Are you sure you have the capitalization right?

Comment: Yes I have permission and the capitalization is correct.

Comment: Since it's read-write mode the file would be created if it didn't exist, but "File not Found" is also an error that computers tend to throw up if there's a permissions issue, so it really sounds like that's what it is.

Comment: Post the stacktrace and show the line that threw the exception

Comment: You're not typically supposed to have permission to write to `C:\ `. This is a permission error. Put it in your `My Documents` folder.

Comment: I have permission, doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your run your Java application as an administrator, you won't have write access to `C:`.

The following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
    RandomAccessFile file1 = new RandomAccessFile("C:\\lol.txt", "rw");
}
```

will give you

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\lol.txt (Access is denied)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Test.Main.main(Main.java:79)
```

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#RandomAccessFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for `RandomAccessFile` constructor states this:

> **FileNotFoundException** - if the mode is "r" but the given string does
>   not denote an existing regular file, or if the mode begins with "rw"
>   but the given string does not denote an existing, writable regular
>   file and a new regular file of that name cannot be created, or if some
>   other error occurs while opening or creating the file

Just move your file to another location, like `C:\Users\You`.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

 at man.main(man.java:10)

Comment: @JohnBlack `FileNotFoundException` is a checked exception. You need to either wrap it in a `try-catch` block or make your method rethrow it by declaring that the method `throws FileNotFoundException`, like I've shown in my answer (I used `Exception` because it's a parent class).

Comment: Ok I have put throws IOException in the main class and now it is working, weird.

Comment: @JohnBlack When you complain about compilation errors in code provided, make sure you have transcribed it correctly. You didn't.